# How to make link with in the element on ruby slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

Unable to make link with in the paragraph

```
p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur voluptates corporis
  a.link href='http://brndstr.com/' target='_blank' perspiciatis.
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwwvGe

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
p 
  | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur voluptates corporis 
  a href='http://brndstr.com/' target='_blank' perspiciatis.
```

Comment: I have just add `|` before paragraph text otherwise html shows `<lorem> ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur voluptates corporis </lorem>`

Comment: Right, sorry missed that. I fixed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The inline way to drop into Ruby code is to put the Ruby code inside of `#{}`.

Assuming that you're using Rails, this is how you'd put in a link that opens in a new tab:

```
p Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur voluptates #{link_to 'corporis', 'http://brndstr.com/', target: "_blank"} perspiciatis.
```